# Json.Net - Explicitly include a single private property

Tags: json.net

I have an object (ViewModel) in which I have a private property that holds some meta-data about the model. I would like to explicitly include this private property in the serializing/deserializing of the object.

Is there a Json.Net Attribute I can add to the property?

```
public class Customer
{

    private string TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
    }
}
```

The "TimeStamp" property's value is injected into the class before it is returned by a service.

I would like this property to survive the json.net serialize/deserialize process so it can be returned to the service.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Andrew's right, the more context we have the better: We don't want to ignore out-of-the-box solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to serialize/deserialize a privete property, decorate it with the `JsonProperty` attribute. Your class should look like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    [JsonProperty]
    private string TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
    }

    public Customer()
    {
        TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
    }
}
```

The assumption here is that you initialize the `TimeStamp` property in the constructor since it is a private property.

The serialization logic is the following:

```
var customer = new Customer
    {
        CustomerId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        FirstName = "Jonh",
        LastName = "Doe"
    };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

The output should be similar to the following one:

```
{
    "TimeStamp": "635543531529938160",
    "CustomerId": "08537598-73c0-47d5-a320-5e2288989498",
    "FirstName": "Jonh",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "Name": "Jonh Doe"
}
```

with the exception of `TimeStamp` and `CustomerId` properties, that would have different values from obvious reasons.